# John's brother as well as I / I as well as John's brother ___ guilty of cheating Jason

Tags: exam-questions

> John's brother as well as I (a) / am guilty (b) of cheating Jason.(c)

This is an error spotting question asked in my exam, a friend told me that part B is wrong, he suggested to replace *am* with *is* , I agree that the helping Verb should agree with the subject preceding *as well as* but I suspect that that part A is wrong . The mistake is placement of first person pronoun. We usually follow rule of 2 3 1  ( 2 = second person 3 = third person 1 = first person ) in normal sentence but in sentences where the essence of sentence is somewhat negative such as we are talking responsibility for some wrong doing for something like that the rule becomes 1 2 3 .So going by this knowledge which I have the correct sentence should be **I as well as John's brother am guilty of cheating Jason.** Am I correct ?

Comment: It's a bad exam question. Partly because most native speakers would use ***me*** rather than ***I*** in this context. But mainly because there's really no good choice with such an awkward subject. Strictly speaking, ***as well as me/I*** is a "parenthetical" element which could in principle be discarded, so the "correct" verb form is the one that agrees with the ***non-optional*** (singular) element ***John's brother***. Which gives us *John's brother, as well as I, **is** guilty of cheating Jason*, but this is such an ugly sentence most people would go for a more complete paraphrasing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think 'I' is correct here because long time ago I was in confusion when to use subjective / objective forms and I guess perhaps on SE or some other website I read that if any such confusion arises omit the preceding part and then check if the sentence sounds correct or not . E.g. consider this sentence - He and her/she is going to market if we omit 'He and' then clearly She fits best here so going by same rule . I fits best in the sentence which I posted in question.

Comment: Well, I've already made the point that I don't think much of your exam question. For similar reasons, I don't think much of your idea about *'I' is correct here*. If you aspire to know how to apply the "rules" of English better than native speakers then I wish you luck, but really there's not much to be gained by learning how to make the best of a bad job with a construction that *simply doesn't suit English syntax* in the first place.

Comment: Since we are talking about two people in _"I as well as John's brother,"_ the plural form _are_ is "correct", but as @FumbleFingers says, this sentence would never be written or spoken by a native English speaker. To avoid the clumsiness of the "correct" verb here, we would say instead _"John's brother and I are **both** guilty of cheating Jason"_, or something similar. In your question, you use the word "rule" several times; but English is not spoken or written according to "rules", and relying upon them often creates problems of the kind described here.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I think essentially this question opens up a can of worms that most native speakers would rather not explore too deeply. The problem is I can't decide whether that makes it a *good* or a *bad* question here on ELL. I guess we'd all agree on *John and his wife **are** here*, and nearly everyone would say *John together with his wife **is** here* - but things get tricky with, say, *John as well as his wife*. Somewhere along the line, ***A and B, A as well as B, A together with B*** there's a potential "phase change" in plurality, but who's to say exactly where that happens.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is a procedural question rather than one regarding language, it seems to me. When a non-native speaker must endure an exam presented by yet another NNS, we can only advise that the OP conform to the "rules" of whatever imaginary version of English is being taught, in the interest of receiving a decent mark and exiting the misbegotten course as soon as possible.

Comment: @P.E. Dant. You are saying plural form is correct than what you have to say about the answer in this question ? https://english.stackexchange.com/q/248742/212388

Comment: You have cited a duplicate question. Instead, read the answers to **[this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/56210/192771)** of which it is a duplicate. The answers (and comments!) are nuanced, which is why I enclosed "correct" in quotes. Speakers avoid the problem by paraphrasing as in my comment. In English, "correct" usage is something only grammarians worry about, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Two natural ways to phrase the sentence would be:

> John's brother and I are guilty of cheating Jason.
>   John's brother is guilty of cheating Jason, and so am I.

It is not idiomatic English to say the following:

> X John's brother as well as I am guilty of cheating Jason.
>   X I as well as John's brother am guilty of cheating Jason.

The "... and so am I" construction I gave in the top example is a good way to keep a sentence simple when the subjects are complex. For example:

> I think that the legal system is too slow, and so does everybody else in my neighbourhood.

Incidentally, the same construction can also make it clear whether people should be considered as a group or as individuals:

> My boss's husband and I own an expensive car. (This suggests that we own it together.)
>   My boss's husband owns an expensive car, and so do I. (We each own a car.)

With that in mind, one of the two versions above might be more appropriate, depending on the context: "John's brother and I are guilty" suggests that we may have collaborated with each other, while "John's brother is guilty, and so am I" suggests that we each cheated Jason individually.

Comment: I look in vain for the word _parenthetical._

Comment: @P.E.Dant Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Msny readers will say that _as well as John's brother_ is a parenthetical, and that this dictates the choice of the singular verb in the OP's example. See the question by our colleague @FumbleFingers at **[ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56210/singular-or-plural-verb-form-where-subject-includes-a-parenthetical-element)** (and his comments above.) Of course paraphrasing is the instinctive way for a NS to avoid the problem, but the subject is a little contentious...

Comment: @P.E.Dant I see; thank you for the explanation. I would say that such parenthetical constructions, however, are rarely idiomatic when one of the subjects is *I*. For instance, it would be odd to say, "I as well as my brother am going to the opera", or even worse, "My brother as well as I is going to the opera".

Comment: Thus the can of worms described by @FumbleFingers above!

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ah, sure. :) That seems very much to me like "None of us *is*" vs. "None of us *are*", or "My family *is*" vs. "My family *are*". I think a similar point could be made about the nuance between "John's brother as well as I *are* guilty" vs. "John's brother as well as I *is* guilty", but it seems that it's best to just rephrase the sentence...

Comment: @Théophile: I don't think the plurality of the construction *none of X* , or of "collective entities" (*families, companies, the police,* etc.), are really that similar to the issue in this question here. Those usages arise all the time, most native speakers simply use whatever plurality they feel comfortable with, and no-one apart from hopelessly misguided pedants would particularly notice if another speaker made different choices to themselves. But with some of the compound subjects covered here, there are simply *no good choices* - every alternative sounds a bit weird to almost everyone.